# Can SHA-1 certs exist in a SHA-2 Microsoft Certificate Authority during migration?

Tags: certificate-authority

I'm starting the process of migrating our internal Microsoft certificate authority to support SHA-2 and haven't been able to find out an answer on the ramifications of this process.  I have found the process itself though.  It looks like the migration process for the internal cert is straight forward.  However, we have multiple certs signed by our CA that support things like wireless connectivity and other devices.  These services will take some time to copy the new cert down to the remote devices before we can go live with it so we need to stage the migration to the new certs outside of the domain cert to SHA-2.  What I need to know is if a SHA-1 cert that already exists on the certificate authority will still exist and continue to function if we do the migration process to migrate to SHA-2 on the domain cert.

Comment: When you say *self-signed*, is that what you really mean or do you actually mean certs signed by your own CA?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Which part? If it was the latter option, please correct the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what confusion you're referring to...?  Self-signed = certificates created by my CA.

Comment: No, that is not what self-signed means. If a certificate is self-signed that means it was signed with its own key.  Root CA certificates are an example of self-signed certs.

Comment: My point being that *self-signed* is a well defined technical term, you have made up a different definition. That is confusing.

Comment: I'm signing with the Microsoft CA.  I updated the question; do you know the answer?

Comment: I would suggest not using the term *self-signed* at all if the certs are not self-signed.  And no, I do not know the details of how the migration is handled in the Microsoft certificate authority so I can't provide answer. (If the certs had been self-signed, however, the answer would have been trivial.)

Comment: This process is called self-signed by Microsoft... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb809042.aspx

Comment: nope, they do not refer to CA-issued certs in your article. They really deal with self-signed certificates.

Comment: @Zebee That document describes how to create a self-signed certificate, not a certificate signed by your CA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upgrade your CA to SHA2, new setting will affect only ***newly*** issued certificates. That is, previously issued certificates won't be changed and will operate as previously until you replace them.